# Unusual function - operations on lists / sets - possible optimization

Tags: algorithms, search-trees, binary-search, python

I have a problem.
Below I present a function in Python.

```
def exist2(Sunion, Sunion_vsum, S, vsum):
    for xunion_id in range(len(Sunion)):
        if(vsum < Sunion_vsum[xunion_id]):

            plist = list(set(S) - set(Sunion[xunion_id]))

            diff = 0
            for i in plist:
                diff = diff + i

            if( Sunion_vsum[xunion_id] == vsum + diff ):
                return 1

        elif(vsum == Sunion_vsum[xunion_id]):
            if( len(set(Sunion[xunion_id]) & set(S)) == len(set(S)) ):
                return 1

    return 0
```

Sunion is a list of lists.
Sunion_vsum is a normal list.

Always len(Sunion) == len(Sunion_vsum)

Similarly, the normal list is S.

vsum is the integer value.

All values are integer (there are no floating point values).

I am looking for a concept how to speed up this algorithm.

Currently, I search all subsequent possibilities.

Can trees/binary search be used somehow in this case?

Anyone can have any idea?

PS. I am looking for a solution for very large len(Sunion).

Comment: This is not programming site, the code in python should be pseudocode instead. Could you give textual description of your problem? "Anyone can have any idea?" Yes, there is no limitation on creativity.

Comment: I'm not looking for a ready solution - code. I am looking for a concept. Of course, I could add a pseudocode, but I think everyone will understand the code above. I will try to add what exactly is the problem.

Comment: "I think everyone will understand the code." Sorry, but I don't. No idea what `range(len(Sunion))` means, or `list(set(S) - set(A[x]))` (variable names trimmed). Don't assume that everybody speaks your favourite programming language.

Comment: Please edit the question to specify the problem in a clear way, that doesn't require knowledge of any particular programming language and doesn't require us to read code.  What are the inputs?  What is the desired output?  How must the two relate?  Please remove the code and replace it with concise pseudocode and/or a careful English specification of the problem.